# How does emacs client work?

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

How does emacsclient communicate with emacs server ? Is it through some kind of socket connection? If so, are there any docs available to read about the protocol ? Where can one read the source of emacsclient?

Comment: yes, sockets, see [source on github](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lib-src/emacsclient.c#L1497)

Comment: I think i got my answer. Thanks for pointing to the source.